# Notepad++ Document Monitor with Remote File

Tags: display, notepad++, remote, documents, tail

I am trying to use Notepad++ to monitor a log file using the plugin Document Monitor. This works great on local files but does not work on remote files.

I have tried both mapping the remote drive and not mapping the remote drive with the same results. Does the Document Monitor plugin not support this functionality?